# How to play HLS video in ChromeCast?

Tags: html, video, chromecast

I want to run video(HLS) from chromecast.

succeeded to run mp4
but..
Video Tag m3u8 not play..

```
<center>
<video src="bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8" controls autoplay ></video>
</center>
```

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) to do that. You have a choice of using either a [Styled Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) or the [Default receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default), or if none satisfies your needs, you can roll out your own [custom receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver). The first two receivers use the Media Player Library and you may want to use that same library if you decide to go with your own custom receiver, as well.

There are a number of sample projects on our [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast) repo that show you how that can be done, please refer to those to see some code samples.